# how to remove decimal places in kendo chart y-axis

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

I am trying to remove kendo chart **"Y-Axis decimal place"** after **pannable & Zoom in/ out**

**Actual chart loaded** 
[image]

**After zoom in & pannable**
 [image]

How can i remove the decimal values from the y-axis, i tried to set the "**Y - axis label format.. but its don't works**"

**Code i tried**

```
 jQuery("#chart_i139_XzCnAHHzIR").kendoChart({
        "chartArea": { "background": "#FFFEFC" },
        "renderAs": "canvas", "title": { "text": "p1" },
        "legend": { "labels": { "template": "#= series.name #" }, "position": "top" },
        "series": [{
            "name": "Male", "type": "line",
            "data": [35171, 36663, 30247, 36479, 34025, 37142, 37295, 36054, 38076, 37725, 34716, 39620, 38296],
            "stack": false, "labels": { "format": "{0:n0}", "visible": true, "position": "above" },
            "style": "smooth"
        }, {
            "name": "Female", "type": "line",
            "data": [34295, 32586, 36872, 35556, 38839, 36932, 34039, 35055, 35429, 35689, 34528, 31777, 33405],
            "stack": false, "labels": { "format": "{0:n0}", "visible": true, "position": "above" },
            "style": "smooth"
        }], "categoryAxis": [{
            "labels": { "rotation": { "angle": "auto" } },
            "majorGridLines": { "width": 1, "color": "#dfdfdf", "visible": false },
            "line": { "visible": true },
            "title": { "text": "years", "position": "left" },
            "categories": ["2008", "2007", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2017", "2016", "2018", "2019"]
        }], "valueAxis": [{ "majorGridLines": { "visible": false } }],
        "transitions": false,
        "tooltip": { "template": "#= series.name #: #= kendo.format(\u0027{0:n0}\u0027,value)  #", "visible": true },
        "pannable": true, "zoomable": true
    });
```

Comment: Issue has been resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been resolved after adding this

```
.ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()
                   .Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0:0}"))
                   .MajorUnit(1))
```

Comment: we need to add it in the kendo chart... Bar, Line i

Comment: This only works if values in axis are below 10. If more than that, like say 500, it fills up the entire axis. Any solution to resolve that?

Comment: @bluepiranha you can write the logic if (axis is less than of 10, you have to assign majorunit(1)) Same like this based on value, You can able to define the majorUnit. Since we also implemented in such scenario.

Comment: @PrasadRaja Yeah thanks. Had to write custom logic. I was hoping Telerik would have a better solution to it.

Comment: @bluepiranha :)

Answer (score 5):

A simpler solution is to append the following configuration to the chart options' valueAxis field:

```
valueAxis: {
    labels: {
        format: "{0:0}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below configuration of your Kendo Chart:

```
{
  series: [{
    name: 'Grand Total',
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    type: 'column',
  }],
  zoomable: {
    mousewheel: {
      lock: 'y',
    },
    selection: {
      lock: 'y',
    },
  },
  pannable: {
    lock: 'y',
  },
  valueAxis: {
    max: 12,
    // labels: {
    //     format: '{0:0}',
    // },
    majorUnit: 1,
  },
  categoryAxis: {
    categories: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]
  },
}
```

The key here is the `valueAxis`. You need to set the `max` and `majorUnit`. If you do a `valueAxis.labels.format: '{0:0}'`, yes the decimals are gone but on maximum zoom it would appear that the bars are not leveled correctly to the y-axis. In fact the bar height/level is correct, the y-axis label is wrong, it's missing a decimal. Comment/uncomment the `valueAxis.labels` and `valueAxis.majorUnit` to see the difference.